# No Performance menu in OEM 12c

Tags: oracle11g, database-administration

Sorry if this is not the right group to post this.  I am trying to generate the
Oracle 12c AWR and ASH report from the Enterprise Manager Database Express 12c tool.  But I do not see the "Performance -> AWR" submenu items when I log in to the tool.  I was trying to follow the steps outlined in this link

https://dbasolved.com/2014/03/12/performance-tuning-with-awr-ash-in-em12c/

and the screenshot shows the Performance -> AWR menu.  In fact, my screen looks very different.  Under Performance, I have Performance Hub and SQL Tuning Advisor.

Does anyone know if I need to install additional Oracle 12c components?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference.  My Oracle 12c is running on Linux.  Just wanted to point this out.  Please respond if you can help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle 12c doesn't have "Enterprise Manager" (as 11g has), it has only  "Enterprise Manager Express" which has limited functionality. If you need full functionality you will have to install "Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 12c".